# How to automatically clear the terminal after every code run in VS Code (No Code Runner, No modifying a Java file)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm interested in being able to **automatically clear the terminal** **every time I** **run my code** (Java program with a main method that may or may not have packages inside the file). Code Runner only runs single class Java files and doesn't work with Java files that have packages so I'm not interested in that.

At the momement I'm running all my Java files by clicking on the "Run and Debug" button in VS Code. I'm aware that I can manually clear the console using Command + K (Mac) but doing this for every run feels repetitive so I'm looking for a way to do this automatically. **Every time I click that run and debug button I'd like for it to clear the console before running an code**. Is there also anyway to show a run button that maps to VS Code's "Run and Debug Button (Similar to the way Code Runner does it by displaying a run/triangle icon (left a screenshot below). Currently I have to make two clicks in order to click "Run and Debug".

I'm **only looking for a solution that doesn't involve changing any Java files** so something that involves changing settings/using an extension/related on VS code. I'm not looking to modify any Java file. Code Runner has the functionality I desire (clear terminal automatically) but doesn't work with all types of Java files so it again can't be used.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804862/836330 A new setting `debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing` is being added to v1.55.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put this line in your java file to clear the terminal.

For **Windows**:

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

For **Linux**:

```
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
```

Comment: I'm not looking to modify any Java files but I'm looking for a solution that is dependendent on VS Code so it can work universally for all files without tinkering with any Java file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your output you can print an ANSI clear screen escape sequence before printing your first line of output.

```
System.out.println("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

Note, this will only work with VTE based terminals like Terminal.app, iTerm, almost all linux terminal emulators, Windows Powershell etc.

Comment: I updated the post. I'm not looking to modify any Java file but only some setting in VS Code. I feel like this should be possible with some modification to VS Code.